# How to share ALL AWS AMI from one account to other AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I need to share all AMI present in one AWS account with another account. Not just existing AMIs, but I need to share new AMI that are built should also be automatically shared with other account.

Is there a AWS native way of doing it?

I can share an individual AMI from AWS console or using CLI:

```
aws ec2 modify-image-attribute --image-id <AMI-ID>  --launch-permission "Add=[{UserId=<NEW_ACCOUNT_ID>}]"
```

Comment: *I need to share new AMI that are built should also be automatically shared with other account* how are you building the AMI?

Comment: I am using a shell script.

I used `aws ec2 modify-image-attribute` for now.

But there is no way to share all and future AMIs at once?

Comment: You should use something like Packer to build virtual machine images. With that, you can easily configure the sharing of the AMI with other accounts

Comment: I can still share using a one liner and is automated. I was just looking for a one time share all. which I think isn't there. Each AMI needs to be shared individually.